# Vertically align parbox text with tabular text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minipage, boxes, parbox

I have a table made with `tabular` that's 3 lines and a `parbox` that's 1 line. I want the text in the `parbox` to line up with the first line of the table, but I can't seem to make that happen. I would like it to look like this:

```
table line 1        parbox line 1
table line 2
table line 3
```

Here's a basic attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  table line 1 \\
  table line 2 \\
  table line 3
  \end{tabular} \parbox[t]{0.4\textwidth}{parbox line 1}
\end{document}
```

Of course I've tried numerous other things as well as other boxes besides `parbox`, but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you already try `\begin{tabular}[t]{l}`?

Comment: @leandriis No, but that did work. If you want to put it as the answer, I'll mark this as answered.